# Kotlin Map with non null values

Tags: collections, kotlin

Let say that I have a Map for translating a letter of a playing card to an integer

```
 val rank = mapOf("J" to 11, "Q" to 12, "K" to 13, "A" to 14)
```

When working with the map it seems that I always have to make a null safety check even though the Map and Pair are immutable:

```
val difference = rank["Q"]!! - rank["K"]!!
```

I guess this comes from that generic types have Any? supertype. Why can't this be resolved at compile time when both Map and Pair are immutable?

Comment: An enum using a `value` property may be preferable for cleaner code. Here's a quick syntax example: http://pastebin.com/1BtynHMN

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not about the implementation of Map (being it Kotlin or Java based). You are using a Map and a map may not have a key hence [] operator returns nullable type.

Comment: Ofcourse ! If key is not present in the map the return is null.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to ask the same question before I found your answer

Answer (score 30):

There is another method for getting [not null value from map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html):

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.getValue(key: K): V
```

throws *NoSuchElementException* - when the map doesn't contain a value for the specified key and no implicit default value was provided for that map.

but operator for *get* == *map[]* [returns nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get.html).

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.get(key: K): V?
```

Answer (score 12):

mapOf() is providing a Map with no guarantees for the presence of a key-- something which is kind of expected especially considering the Java implementation of Map.

While I might personally prefer sticking with null-safe calls and elvis operators, it sounds like you'd prefer cleaner code at the call site (especially considering you know these keys exist and have associated non-null values). Consider this:

```
class NonNullMap<K, V>(private val map: Map<K, V>) : Map<K, V> by map {
    override operator fun get(key: K): V {
        return map[key]!! // Force an NPE if the key doesn't exist
    }
}
```

By delegating to an implementation of map, but overriding the get method, we can guarantee that return values are non-null. This means you no longer have to worry about !!, ?., or ?: for your usecase.

Some simple test code shows this to be true:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    val rank = nonNullMapOf("J" to 11, "Q" to 12, "K" to 13, "A" to 14)
    val jackValue: Int = rank["J"] // Works as expected
    println(jackValue)
    val paladinValue: Int = rank["P"] // Throws an NPE if it's not found, but chained calls are considered "safe"
    println(jackValue)
}

// Provides the same interface for creating a NonNullMap as mapOf() does for Map
fun <K, V> nonNullMapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>) = NonNullMap(mapOf<K, V>(*pairs))
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't achieve that until Kotlin changes. As others have pointed out, this doesn't have to do with mutability but the fact that Java's Maps accept **null** as valid values. At the moment, Kotlin's `*Map` classes has the exact implementation as Java's `*Map` classes.

If you still want to achieve non-null-value only map, you'll need to implement your own e.g. extending `Map` or wrap around it

More specifically, behind the scene, `mapOf` gives us a Kotlin's LinkedHashMap which is not a different class but a just a **typealias** of Java's LinkedHashMap

Maps.kt

```kotlin
public fun <K, V> mapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>): Map<K, V> =
    if (pairs.size > 0) pairs.toMap(LinkedHashMap(mapCapacity(pairs.size))) else emptyMap()
```

TypeAliases.kt

```kotlin
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias LinkedHashMap<K, V> = java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>
```

You can try `map.getValue(key)` instead of `map.get(key)` but I personally think that's unclean and confusing.

Perhaps some others from Dan Lew [here](https://blog.danlew.net/2017/06/14/convincing-the-kotlin-compiler-that-code-is-safe/) would be useful for you?

My Kotlin version is `1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-3`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a decent solution:

```
val rank = object {
    val rankMap = mapOf("J" to 11, "Q" to 12, "K" to 13, "A" to 14)
    operator fun get(key: String): Int = rankMap[key]!!
}
```

```
val difference = rank["Q"] - rank["K"]
```